# Entity framework with Web Api returning object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am new to entity framework. I have following objects

```
 public partial class lr
    {
        public lr()
        {
            this.lr_history = new HashSet<lr_history>();
            this.people = new HashSet<person>();
        }

        public int _id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<lr_history> lr_history { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<person> people { get; set; }
```

In my Web Api controller I have following code

```
 public class lrController : ApiController
{
    private CTM db = new CTM();

    // GET api/addL
    public IEnumerable<lr> Getlr()
    {
        from a in DbContext.Activities 
        return db.lr.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

In above Get method it returns lr but i want to return my own object like

```
   lr.id
   lr.name
   lr_history.description
   lrh_history.rate
```

Can anyone show me how to achieve this? Than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new model:

```
class HistoryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HistoryDescription { get; set; }
    public string HistoryRate { get; set; }
}
```

and return that:

```
public IEnumerable<HistoryModel> Getlr()
{
    from a in DbContext.Activities 
    return db.lr.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new HistoryModel 
                                 { 
                                     Id = x.id,
                                     Name = x.name,
                                     HistoryDescription = x.history.description,
                                     HistoryRate = x.history.rate
                                 });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. One more question when I need to write back to the database using same model, how would i go about that using the id. Thanks

Comment: @J.Davidson You should create a new question rather than asking more questions

Comment: `HistoryModel` is a DataTransferObject. You'll need to construct an EntityFramework Entity from `HistoryModel` and update the db using that.

Comment: Not using EntityFramework, but it did exactly what I wanted

Answer (score -1):

Instade of **return db.lr.AsEnumerable();**

try this
 **return db.lr.ToList();**

Comment: This is not what he wants. He wants to return his own type.